# Add to cart in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After adding the informations in my modals, i'm trying to insert a quantity selector to have the amount of the product that the client choose on my website to then manage the cart. Can explain me how should I proceed to do so in Javascript ?

John Simmons

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="bouton" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="showProduct(1);">Add to cart</button>

        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="product_nom"></span></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                <span><b>Product tag : </b></span><span id="product_tag"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                 <span><b>Product price : </b></span>
                <span id="product_price"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <span><b>Product image : </b></span>
                <img id="product_image" src=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <span><b>Product description : </b></span>
                <span id="product_description"></span>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Javascript

```
function produits(tag, nom, price, imagesrc, description){
 this.Tag = tag;
 this.Nom = nom;
 this.Price = price;
 this.SRC = imagesrc;
 this.Description = description;
}

var produit = [];

//6x for my 6 products 
produit.push(new produits(1, "nom", 35, "path/to/img","Description"));

function showProduct(productId){
    document.getElementById("product_tag").innerHTML = produit[productId-1].Tag;
  document.getElementById("product_nom").innerHTML = produit[productId-1].Nom;
  document.getElementById("product_price").innerHTML = produit[productId-1].Price;
  document.getElementById("product_image").src = produit[productId-1].SRC;
  document.getElementById("product_description").innerHTML = produit[productId-1].Description;
```

Comment: You can add a dropdown list on your modal and allow visitors to select a quantity from the list.

Comment: I did it, I used an number input but how can I use it to transfert it in my cart ? @TejSoft

Comment: How are you doing it now? What is the "produit.push()" function call doing?

Comment: It's too fill my array with products informations, I then did a function called Add to cart with var quantityProduct = document.getElementByID("quantity").value; (Quantity id was added in my html) @TejSoft